# Atomic if(A && B)?

Tags: c, concurrency, atomic

Is there a way to make an atomic `if` with a conjunction? That is, can I somehow atomically test `if(A && B)` in C? If it short circuits in the first conjunct then that's no problem, but if it doesn't, by the time that it's checking `B`, `A` might have changed. Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Without using coarse locks or semaphores.

Comment: Use an appropriate synchronization object.

Comment: @Jon: Could you use more words?

Comment: Since there is more than one assembly instruction involved, You can make them atomic only by providing explicit synchronization. i.e: bundle the two instructions together as a logical unit and apply a lock(*mutex or semaphore or ...*) before and after their usage.

Comment: @DervinThunk: What he said. :)

Comment: Yes, fine, I was hoping for a little more sophistication. I don't want to use locks... at least not with that level of granularity, hence the "atomic" question. I was wondering if I can do something with a CAS or DCAS or NCAS, or creatively using `__builtin_sync`

Comment: @Alok we don't know how many assembly instructions are there, maybe one, but it's irrelevant. (Anyway, the question makes no sense as stated: what if both A and B change between the test and the *body* of `if`?)

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: That's not my issue here. Focus on the question. I will deal with the body when I come to it.

Comment: @Dervin don't try to moderate comments, focus on improving your question instead. Platform? Memory model? Why are you sure there's no reordering, do you use `volatile`? Something like "keep A and B as two bytes in the same aligned machine word, so the load is atomic" could be the answer, but not with that little information you give.

Comment: @Dervin: That must be one of the most rude and short-sighted comment I've ever seen on StackOverflow.

Comment: @NiklasB. Sorry to have hurt your feelings. Now, do you have something to contribute by way of an answer?

Comment: @DervinThunk I really dislike the question. There is far too little background specified (machine, system, anything) for the real complexity of the question. Besides, as Anton pointed, the question seems to make little sense as the change in these values may occur just after the check.

Answer (score 4):

You have to manually synchronize access to both objects! How else would you like to happen?

It is the fundamental idea of parallel programming, two things can happen at a time, unless you yourself make it otherwise.

pseudocode sample:

```
//Comparison:
{
  lock(Amutex);
  lock(Bmutex);
  bool result = A && B;
  unlock(Amutex);
  unlock(Bmutex);

  if (result) // ...
}

//assignment:
{
  lock(Amutex);
  A = val;
  unlock(Amutex);
}
```

Comment: This should probably be a comment, as it doesn't seem to provide an actual answer.

Comment: @Paul R: Soo, what then would you consider an "actual answer"? Someone doing all of OP's work for him/her?

Answer (score 2):

If A absolutely must not change until you check B, you can use a lock/mutex (or some other synchronization primitive, e.g. a critical section) on A, as it's been suggested.

You could also join A and B into a single aligned 32-bit or 64-bit integer that you'd always read and write as a whole atomically, again, using a synchronization primitive or CAS or special CPU instructions, as it's been suggested.

If your system is single-processor, you could also inhibit all interrupts or scheduling while reading and writing A and B to achieve the same effect. This won't work on multi-processor systems if A or B can be modified by different CPUs.

If you can tolerate changes in A and are only interested in seeing the same value of A after reading B as before reading B, you could read A twice and B in between. Care must be taken to ensure the order of the reads. volatiles and/or memory barriers can help with enforce the order.

All of this is specific to the target hardware, OS and the compiler, and the question cannot be answered in a detailed manner without knowing these details.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `mutex` or a `semaphore` to protect `A` from changing.

Or you could try this.

```
bool A_initial;
if( (A_initial = A) && B && (A==A_initial) ) {  /*A has not changed and 
                                                condition evaluated to true.  */
}
else if (A ! = A_initial){ /* You have to redo the if() or 
                              whatever if A is changed  */
}
```

Comment: A little more detail and perhaps an example could make this a useful answer.

Comment: @PaulR You think this will be a reasonable solution, since the OP of question did an edit.

Comment: I don't think the second suggestion will work, and the OP has moved the goalposts now, as you noted.